# Stack sequence of values x number of times

Tags: r

I have a vector 'values' of length 'gs', with discrete values. I want to create a column where 'values' is stacked 'gs' times. E.g.:

```
gs = 3

values = [1, 2, 3]

### stack output

[,1]
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: `matrix(rep(values, gs), ncol = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `rep` command to repeat your vector `gs` number of times, and feed it into `matrix` which turns it into one column.

```
> gs <- 3
> values <- c(1,2,3)
> matrix(rep(values, gs))
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    2
 [6,]    3
 [7,]    1
 [8,]    2
 [9,]    3
```